# How to get only matched element in DOM when using getElementByTagName?

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementsbytagname

I want to get one element in the content that its innerHTML is "SOMETHING". The tag name is

```
<div>
```

and it does not have id.

```
<div class="hfvbuerfv iygerifyg r">
   <div class="iyg8ybwef g irfg">
      <div class="oiuh9 iyg y">SOMETHING</div>
      <div class="iojuiohi"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I tried this:

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (i=0; i<all.length; i++) {
   if (all[i].innerHTML.toString().includes("SOMETHING")) {
      console.log(all[i]);
   }
}
```

but I also get all parent div.

Consider that, I don't want to use JQuery or XPATH. I just want to do it with pure javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get all parent nodes as well because the innerHTML of the parent nodes contains the div node with `SOMETHING` in it. I think you need to add a check that the only child of the matched div node is a text node and that contains the nodeValue of "SOMETHING":

```js
function findSomethingNode() {
  var allDivs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

  for (var i = 0; i < allDivs.length; ++i) {
    // Check for a single child that is a text node
    // (nodeType === 3) that has the text (nodeValue) "SOMETHING"
    if (allDivs[i].childNodes.length === 1 && allDivs[i].childNodes[0].nodeType === 3 && allDivs[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue === "SOMETHING") {
      return allDivs[i];
    }
  }
}

// This logs the found node
console.log(findSomethingNode());
```

```html
<div class="hfvbuerfv iygerifyg r">
  <div class="iyg8ybwef g irfg">
    <div class="oiuh9 iyg y">SOMETHING</div>
    <div class="iojuiohi"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`includes` will also match the parent since that will also include "SOMETHING".

Like these strings will also return true.

```js
"SOMETHINGHERE".includes("SOMETHING")
"HERESOMETHING".includes("SOMETHING")
```

If you want the exact match just check if the `innerHTML` is same

```js
if (all[i].innerHTML == "SOMETHING" ) {
      console.log(all[i]);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote is finding the divs up to the div in which the text is present.
You can store the content for each iteration if the condition satisfies.
Like this, you will have the last div that meets the condition in the variable.
And at last print the variable.

You can obtain your required result by st

```
<div class="hfvbuerfv iygerifyg r">
   <div class="iyg8ybwef g irfg">
      <div class="oiuh9 iyg y">SOMETHING</div>
      <div class="iojuiohi"></div>
   </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var all = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (i=0; i<all.length; i++) {
       if (all[i].innerHTML.toString().includes("SOMETHING")) {
          current = all[i]
       }
    }
    console.log(current);
</script>
```